# How to turn off GPS from cordova android app [android API 29]

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, gps

I am building a android api 29 app which have a functionality to turn off the GPS in a button click. I am able to turn on using the below link https://github.com/rodrigo-md/cordova-dialog-gps. Can someone help mw on this?

Comment: I don't think you can turn of an activity that wasn't started by Cordova

Comment: im able to turn on using the cordova-dialog-gps plugin